# link to index in sapper creates a second index page

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

First of all sorry if the title is a bit unclear, I could not find a clear and concise way to describe my issue.

I'm following along this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujbE0mzX-CU to build an app of my own, and after doing the same thing as he does with his [state].svelte route, I find myself a little bit stuck when I try to link to my index page. I want the logo on the top left to bring me back to the index page when it's clicked, but if I do

```html
<a href ="index" class="navbar-item">
  <img src="myimage" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

It brings me to localhost:3000/index, which is not my homepage (it's localhost:3000). It considers the name index as if it was a state in the tutorial. Do you know how to solve this issue ? The code in my [state].svelte page is here for easier comprehension :

```html
<script context="module">

  export async function preload(page, session) {
    return { state: page.params['state'] };
  }

</script>

<script>
  import { Component1, Component2 } from '../components/export.js';


  export let state;
</script>

<h1>{state}</h1>

<Component1 />
<Component2/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `/` instead of `index`

```html
<a href="/" class="navbar-item">
  <img src="myimage" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an index file and put this on

```
<a href="index.html">Go to new page</a>
```